# Problems with remote shared objects Fms Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-media-server, shared-objects

I'm trying to develop an application where simultaneous users can interact and i need to have a persistent remote shared object with the list of users currently in session.
When a new user enter in the session he get the server's object with the list. That list was supose to have all the others users in session but is undefined.

I'm doing this first:

```
users_so = SharedObject.getRemote("users_so", nc.uri, true);
users_so.connect( nc );
users_so.addEventListener( SyncEvent.SYNC, usersSyncHandler );
```

then i set property to shared object

```
remoteUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    remoteUsers.addItem(displayName);
    users_so.setProperty("usersID", remoteUsers);
```

and finaly i put users in the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution that works better for me:

It consists in calling remote funcions on server and then broadcast to all clients. The clientes then apply the necessery changes making the solution a lot more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you need to use `sharedObject.setDirty("usersID");`

SharedObject can't know, that you changed content of ArrayCollection, because the reference to it didn't change. You can use setDirty() to force synch.

> **Note:** The SharedObject.setProperty()
>   method implements the setDirty()
>   method. In most cases, such as when
>   the value of a property is a primitive
>   type like String or Number, you would
>   use setProperty() instead of setDirty.
>   However, when the value of a property
>   is an object that contains its own
>   properties, use setDirty() to indicate
>   when a value within the object has
>   changed. In general, it is a good idea
>   to call setProperty() rather than
>   setDirty(), because setProperty()
>   updates a property value only when
>   that value has changed, whereas
>   setDirty() forces synchronization on
>   all subscribed clients.

I am using simple dynamic object for this. Client has read-only SharedObject and server decides when to add/remove client from this SharedObject.

`m_so` is `SharedObject` (remote), `m_userList` is `Object` (local)

```
if(m_so.data.userList != null) {                                                          
    for (var key:String in m_so.data.userList) {                                                     
        if(m_userList[key] == null) {                                                 
            _addUser(m_so.data.userList[key]);            
        }                                                 
    }                                                     
    for(var clientId:String in m_userList) {                                                     
        if(m_so.data.userList[clientId] == null) {                                                 
            _removeUser(clientId);                        
        }                                                 
    }
}                                                     

application.onAppStart = function () {

    userList = {};

    so = SharedObject.get("roster", false);
    so.setProperty("userList", userList);
}

application.onConnect = function (client /*Client*/, userId /*string*/) {
    application.acceptConnection(client);    
    client.userId = userId;
    userList[userId] = userId;
    so.setProperty("userList", userList);
}

application.onDisconnect = function (client /*Client*/) {
    var userId = client.userId;
    delete userList[userId];
    so.setProperty("userList", userList);
}
```